# Combine an array of values inside array of similar objects which has matching key value pair using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have the following object:

```
  a = [
{id: 1, comp: 'ans', stat: 'www', value: ['1', '2']},
{id: 2, comp: 'qsn', stat: 'xxx', value: ['a', 'b']},
{id: 3, comp: 'ans', stat: 'yyy', value: ['3', '4']},
{id: 4, comp: 'qsn', stat: 'zzz' ,value: ['c', 'd']}
]
```

I wanted the best possible way to combine the value array inside of the objects where the key `comp` matches and the other properties that do not match have the property of the first element intact and concat only the `values` array. The output I want to achieve in the above scenario is :

```
[
{id: 1, comp: 'ans', stat: 'www', value: ['1', '2', '3', '4']},
{id: 2, comp: 'qsn', stat: 'xxx', value: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Search for "Group array of objects by property javascript", that will help you create two arrays. To merge, do something like `group.reduce((o1, o2) => ({ ...o1, value: o1.value.concat(o2.value) }))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the objects by `comp` using the function `Array.prototype.reduce` and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

```js
const a = [{id: 1, comp: 'ans', stat: 'www', value: ['1', '2']},{id: 2, comp: 'qsn', stat: 'xxx', value: ['a', 'b']},{id: 3, comp: 'ans', stat: 'yyy', value: ['3', '4']},{id: 4, comp: 'qsn', stat: 'zzz' ,value: ['c', 'd']}],
      result = Object.values(a.reduce((a, {comp, value, ...rest}) => {
        (a[comp] || (a[comp] = {...rest, comp, value: []})).value.push(...value);
        return a;
      }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @vivek-jain the css is to expand the console, don't remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I think a more readable approach is necessary

```
const a = [{
        id: 1,
        comp: 'ans',
        stat: 'www',
        value: ['1', '2']
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        comp: 'qsn',
        stat: 'xxx',
        value: ['a', 'b']
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        comp: 'ans',
        stat: 'yyy',
        value: ['3', '4']
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        comp: 'qsn',
        stat: 'zzz',
        value: ['c', 'd']
    }
]

const result = [];

for (let aChild of a) {
    const sameComp = result.find(res => res.comp === aChild.comp);
    if (sameComp) {
        sameComp.value = sameComp.value.concat(aChild.value);
    } else {
        result.push(aChild);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```